# Как лучше организовать вложения в сообщения

Tags: php

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Добавлять в текст сообщения некий тег (допустим) `<#$au[полная ссылка на файл]au$#>`
2. Создавать запись в бд, с `id` сообщения и выискивать подобные записи

Comment: Без разницы, во втором случае не используемые вложения ты без труда можешь подчистить

Comment: Проблема в том, где меньше нагрузка... Парсинг каждого сообщения , или отдельные таблицы

Comment: А зачем тебе парсить?

Comment: Вариант 1 ( <#$au[полная ссылка на файл]au$#>)  ибо вложение должно быть визуально оформлено с возможностью редактирования сообщения

Comment: Так это на стороне клиента решается на js и css, для удобства можно класс какой-нибудь задать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проблема в том, где меньше нагрузка... Парсинг каждого сообщения , или
>   отдельные таблицы

Если у вас сообщения имеют вид:

```
123
<#$au[полная ссылка на файл]au$#>
<#$au[полная ссылка на файл]au$#>
```

То парсинг будет по профитнее в **малом масштабе**. Но никакой гибкости и масштабируемости тут нет, поэтому вычеркиваем.

Если в сообщении будет куча текста и там в конце несколько вложений то конечно БД профитнее.

В больших масштабах надо смотреть всегда в сторону БД, вопрос обычно встает в том, какой инструмент использовать, например можно использовать субд(mysql, postgre и т.д.), можно файлики использовать и т.д.

Если хранить в файликах (например новость имеет `id=2`, где-то у нас есть директория и в ней файлик `2.txt` где наши ссылки) - то это будет быстрее чем каждый раз дергать субд (но стоит отметить что у вас индексированные запросы, а индексированные-селекты выполняются довольно быстро при любых объемах бд). Но с другой стороны субд предлагает больше возможности манипулировать этими данными (например, если у вас сменится id сообщения, то субд автоматически сменит и у вложений, при условия наличия связей).

P.S. Конечно мы говорим о копейках, если у вас 10 человек запросят одновременно новость, скорее всего, при любом из вариантов (даже парсинге) вы нагрузки не получите. Однако если смотреть в больших масштабах, профитным будут файлы, НО они не дают такой гибкости как СУБД, поэтому предпочтение, в вашем случае, надо отдать именно субд.

P.S.2. Плюс ко всему, обычно все запросы к субд кешируют (в те-же файлики, либо memcached и т.п.). Т.е. если 10 человек запрашивают одну новость, зачем 10 раз дергать БД? правильно? можно один раз сделать запрос, на часик закешировать полученный результат, и другим уже выводить этот кеш, спустя час опять запросик и т.д.

Comment: Идея состоит в том, что файловая система  разделенная по древовидному типу будет хранить в себе файл, <#$au[полная ссылка на файл]au$#> тут будет ссылка, но смысл заключается в том, чтоб визуально оформить можно наверное js ом заменять на стороне пользователя данный тег на html разметку

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев вы спросили где меньше нагрузка, я ответил. теперь вы говорите что - визуально оформить. Визуально оформить можно тоже любым способом. Можно и с БД запрашивать файлы, возвращать клиенту в формате JSON, и тогда парсить сообщение не надо, берем наш json и манипулируем как надо.